# Rails paperclip updating users image failing due to attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload profile image for the users profile. The `users` table has the following column `avatar`

```
<%= form_for(:avatar, :remote => true , :url => '/profiles/uploadProfileImage',:multipart => true , :html => { :id => 'upload_qimage'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id , :value => Digest::MD5.hexdigest((current_user.id + Time.now.to_i).to_s )[0,7] %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar, :onchange => "$(this).parents('form').submit(); before_submit() ; ",class: "image_textbox"  %>
<% end %>
```

The user.rb has the following piece of code:

```
attr_accessible :avatars_attributes
has_attached_file :avatar,:path => ':rails_root/public/assets/profileimage/:basename_:style.:extension', :styles => {:small => '415x325>' }
```

And the controller:

```
def uploadProfileImage
  @user = User.find(:id => current_user.id)
  @user.update_attributes(:avatars_attributes =>   params[:avatar])
  if @user.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

It is giving me an error saying  `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: avatars_attributes:`

The log:

```
Started PUT "/profiles/uploadProfileImage" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-24 14:04:16 +0530
Processing by ProfilesController#uploadProfileImage as JS
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xbe31de4 @original_filename="129f3a8_1_small.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"129f3a8_1_small.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20131024-3430-1rdcqt8>>}, "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Zkr4+9+DkRuPiS4pUzymOOsc0gRWM8GrGJcfKoVa83w=", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error - Can't mass-assign protected attributes: avatar:
  activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
  activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
  activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
  activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:216:in `block in update_attributes'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:215:in `update_attributes'
  app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:31:in `uploadProfileImage'
```

Line 30-31 is :

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Model:**

```
attr_accessible :avatar
has_attached_file :avatar,:path => ':rails_root/public/assets/profileimage/:basename_:style.:extension', :styles => {:small => '415x325>' }
```

**In View file:**

```
<%= form_for current_user, :remote => true , :url => '/profiles/uploadProfileImage', :multipart => true , :html => { :id => 'upload_qimage'} do |f| %>

  <%= f.file_field :avatar, :onchange => "$(this).parents('form').submit(); before_submit() ; ",class: "image_textbox"  %>

<% end %>
```

**In Controller:**

```
def uploadProfileImage

  @user = User.find(:id => current_user.id)
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: can you provide the log printing on rails log ?

Comment: Works now. There was some other problem.